# R function about weibull distribution with 3 parameters

Tags: r, distribution, model-fitting

I'm here with a problem of fitting distribution function for weibull distribution with 3 parameters, through I have got it for weibull distribution with 2 parameters(i.e., pweibull),but Still I can't find any thing for weibull distribution with 3 parameters.so,can anyone tell me what the function would be.

Comment: Please take a look at How to make a great R reproducible example, to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: Please use google before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [this](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/The_Weibull_Distribution) third parameter is just a shift

So, along the lines

```
dweibull3 <- function(x, shape, scale = 1, shift = 0, log = FALSE) {
    dweibull(x - shift, shape, scale, log)
}

pweibull3 <- function(q, shape, scale = 1, shift = 0, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) {
    pweibull(q - shift, shape, scale, lower.tail, log.p)
}
```

Comment: The function "weibull3" is not running in r.can you say any alternative way to run the above code interms of weibull distribution with 3 parameters or package in where I can run weibull3 easily.

Comment: @RahulJayekar what exactly is not running? It is working for me, R 3.5.3, x64, Win10